# Calculating force delivered by an EM wave on a cone

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, electromagnetic-radiation, intensity

> **Question:**
>
> A parallel light beam of radiation intensity $I$ is incident on a solid right circular cone of height $H$ and radius $R$ as shown in figure. Calculate the net force experienced by the cone if, surface of cone is perfectly
>
> - absorbing
> - reflecting

[image: radiation on cone]

As for an absorbing surface,

$$p = \frac Uc \Rightarrow F = \frac{dp}{dt} = \frac{IA_{||}}{c}$$

So, for the first case, $A_{||} = \pi R^2$, then

$$F=\frac{I\pi R^2}{c}$$
which was correct answer. The second part seems to be obvious as for a reflecting surface,

$$F=\frac{2I\pi R^2}{c}$$
However, this wasn't the given answer. Where am I wrong?

---

The correct answer to second part was,

$$F=\frac{2I\pi R^4}{c(R^2+H^2)}$$

Comment: Please state the source?

Answer (score 0):

The force from reflection is only exactly twice the force from absorption if the light rays **retrace their original paths** after reflection. In this situation, this isn't true - the direction of outgoing rays is different from the direction of incoming rays, and the force on any given point is going to be perpendicular to the surface at that point and related to the momentum change of the ray before and after reflection. Since the normal vectors to the surface don't all align, there's going to be some cancellation.

Comment: Yeah, I know that $p=U/c$ in case of retracing. So, in second case, $$p_{\perp}=2U(\sin\theta)/c\Rightarrow F=2I(\pi Rl\sin\theta)/c=2I\pi R^2/c$$No?